# SNAPSHOT SAVED in Cache/Snapshots

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

**Hi every1,
Snapshots of my app are being logged in Cache/Snapshots folder. I just don't need to log these snapshots due to the security concerns. 
I have used this below piece of code, which I got this from net to remove the snapshots which are saved :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier __block bgTask;
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    if(UIBackgroundTaskInvalid != bgTask) {
        // Start the long-running task to kill app after some secs and return immediately.
        dispatch_after( dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, KILL_IN_BACKGROUND_AFTER_SECS * 1e09), 
                       dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           if(goingToQuit) exit(0);
                           [app endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
                       });
    }
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // cancel ongoing background suicide.
    goingToQuit = NO;

}
```

I dont want to log these snapshots, please advice on this.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not adding code to delete files :(  Please refer my code snippet

```
- (void) deleteFiles {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self beingBackgroundUpdateTask];
        NSError *error = nil;
        // dirPath is path to your snapshot directory 
        NSArray *directoryContents = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:&error];
        if (error == nil) {
            for (NSString *path in directoryContents) {
                 NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
                 BOOL removeSuccess = [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
                 if (!removeSuccess) {
                     // Error handling
                     ...
                 }
            }
        } else {
            // Error handling
        }

        // Do something with the result 
       [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    });
}
- (void) beingBackgroundUpdateTask {
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
}

- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundUpdateTask];
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Comment: creator... So I need to call [self deleteFiles] in ApplicationDidEnterBackground.. Is that your saying ?

Comment: When ever you need to perform deletion